# How to call and Handle request third party API in Ruby on Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

I want to use third party API  and want to make a put and post request and get the response from API in my Rails Application

Ruby and Rails Version of My Application is Below -

Current Version of Ruby -1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5

May I know which Gem should I have to use?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried researching this yourself? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need HTTP client library to make http request and get response

You can use any of available ruby libraries/gems

1. faraday
2. httpclient
3. httparty

I ordered by my preference. More libraries found here https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients.html

You can find the usages here https://github.com/BoTreeConsultingTeam/magpress where I used faraday